# Hit Camera Doesn't Recognize Mouse Position When Display 2 Is Activated

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I have to cameras: one I have set over the map (Cam 1), and one I have as a follow camera (Cam 2).

I am using Cam 1 as a "Hit Camera": It is supposed to fetch the coordinates of the mouse where it hit the ground. Once it does that, I can use the coordinates to move the player and camera as I please.

The problem is whenever I start the scene and switch to Display 2 (the display that Cam 2 is on), the Cam 1 won't register the mouse input properly. It works perfectly fine on Display 1 (the display that Cam 1 is on), though. Why is this happening, and how do I fix this?

I don't have any code for Cam 2, yet, but here's the code I have for Cam 1:

```
public class HitCameraController : MonoBehaviour {
    //public
    public static Vector3 mousePos;
    public static bool gotMouse;
    public static bool mouseMoved;

    //v3
    private Vector3 lastMouseMovement;

    void Start ()
    {
        gotMouse = false;
        mouseMoved = false;
        lastMouseMovement = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    }

    void Update () {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        LayerMask ground = LayerMask.GetMask("GroundLayer");
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 300, ground))
        {
            //Debug.Log("Hi");
            mousePos = new Vector3(hit.point.x, 0.0f, hit.point.z);
            if(mousePos == lastMouseMovement)
            {
                mouseMoved = false;
            }
            else
            {
                mouseMoved = true;
                lastMouseMovement = mousePos;
            }
            gotMouse = true;
        }
        else
        {
            gotMouse = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of `Camera.main` try it with a reference to the camera you want to use. either create a public field and set it up in the inspector, or if the script is attached to the camera get it with `GetComponent<Camera>()`

Comment: @yes GetComponent<Camera>() did the trick. Now I just have to adjust the rest myself.

Comment: dont forget that `GetComponent` is taxing, you should never use it in `Update`, instead get the reference in `Start` and store it in a private field. (if you knew that, ignore what i just said)

Comment: `GetComponent` is less expensive than `Camera.main` as `Camera.main` is just a blind remap to `GameObject.Find` which searches the entire scene hierarchy.

Comment: @Draco18s ah, good to know. also good i dont like to use any of those provided static fields anyway. :D

Comment: @yes I still use it on occasion, when I'm using only one camera and saving a reference to reuse. But totally understandable.  I learned about it in a Unity talk video a couple months back.

Comment: @Draco18s do you have a link to that video?

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko I think it's [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-oZa4Fb12U&t=2121s). I've also watched [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_wxitgdx-UI).